# How to update bridge table in DAL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application (n-tier) and I am working in my DAL.
I need to do the update query on a bridge table:

[image: The table]

But both of the columns are part of the primary key. So when I need to update I need to change the primary key basically.

My code:

```
// Update
public void UpdateKarakterInTeam(ICreatedTeam createdTeam)
{
    int TeamId = GetTeamIntFromId(createdTeam.TeamNaam);
    int KarakterId = GetCharacterIntFromName(createdTeam.KarakterNaam);

    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "UPDATE Team_Karakter SET KarakterId = @KarakterId WHERE TeamId = @TeamId AND KarakterId= @KarakterId;";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamId", TeamId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KarakterId", KarakterId);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to update `KarakterId` to a new given `KarakterId`, but I can not do this query, because what I do now is:

```
UPDATE Team_Karaker 
SET KarakterId = @KarakterId 
WHERE TeamId = @TeamId AND KarakterId = @KarakterId
```

But the second `KarakterId` (in the query above) is the `KarakterId` that should be the original `KarakterId` (of the `Karakter` I want to edit), and the first `KarakterId` should be the changes or new given Id.

Should I try and save the first input in the DAL and use that for the query, or is there is easier way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: command.ExecuteNonQuery() returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed.  When you do a UPDATE get a value of zero it means the keys are not in the database and you need to do an INSERT instead of UPDATE.  Likewise if you do an INSERT and get a zero it means the keys are in database and you need to do an UPDATE.

Comment: Maybe you just need to **delete** the old row and insert a new one .....

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!